# Adding a data dictionary to Trimble R1 reciever through ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector, trimble

I don't even know how to properly google this effectively, so maybe someone can help me on here. My company purchased a Trimble R1 GNSS Receiver. The data is managed through ArcGIS Online. I have a data dictionary that I need to use, but I can't figure out how I am supposed to upload it in ArcGIS Online. I have been creating Feature Layers to collect other data with generic data dictionaries - I use Field Notes Template currently.

Is there a way to upload a data dictionary to ArcGIS Online to use with ArcGIS Collector on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tech session from the user conference in 2018 talking about how to use ArcGIS Online, Collector and high accuracy GPS receivers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QkYNJtNoQE

Comment: That was super helpful, especially in regards to setting a transformation. However, unless I missed it, did it cover if you can upload a pre-existing data dictionary? I actually figured out that to edit attribute fields I just needed to switch from Overview to Data and edit the fields that way. But I still haven't figured out how to add a Trimble Data Dictionary file to a Feature Layer.

Comment: you will have to add the fields prior to publishing or after using the workflow you are currently using. Or you can do this through the REST api https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/add-to-definition-feature-layer-.htm